# Merge two rows into one row with one column having distinct values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two experiences of the same exp_seek_id based on a column named abroad which is either 'Y' or 'N'. I have calculated the sum of all abroad experiences and the sum of all domestic experiences. So far, I have successfully fetched the above results but I am getting two rows of the same PK . Is it possible to get both experiences that are ( abroad and domestic) in a single row?

So far, I am getting this :

```
EXP_SEEK_ID | Experience | Abroad
      146           7        Y
      146           3        N
```

Expected Result:

```
EXP_SEEK_ID | Abroad | Domestic
      146           7      3
```

My code :

```
Select exp_seek_id ,experience,
SUM( extract (year from exp_date_to)- extract (year from exp_date_from) )
From 
job_seek_experience where 
exp_seek_id = 146
Group By 
exp_seek_id,experience
```

Comment: Somehow that doesn't add up. Is there a column `experience` that's the number you want to show or the `sum(extract(...) - extract(...))` expression? The query you show doesn't match any of the results you posted. I recommend you edit the question and add the table's structure (as `CREATE TABLE` statement), sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statement) and the desired result with that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your final result as my input but it will be easy for you to modify the script for your situtation.

```
create table exp_table
(exp_seek_id number, experience number, abroad char);

insert into exp_table
values(146, 7, 'Y');
insert into exp_table
values(146, 3, 'N');



with abroad_exp as
        (select exp_seek_id, 
                experience, 
                abroad 
         from exp_table
         where abroad = 'Y'),
     domestic_exp as
        (select exp_seek_id, 
                experience, 
                abroad  
         from exp_table
         where abroad = 'N')
select /*+ parallel */
  abroad_exp.exp_seek_id,
  abroad_exp.experience as abroad,
  domestic_exp.experience as domestic
from abroad_exp,
     domestic_exp
where abroad_exp.exp_seek_id = domestic_exp.exp_seek_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do that is to combine `SUM` + `DECODE`, e.g.

```
SQL> with job_seek_experience
  2    (exp_seek_id, experience, abroad) as
  3    (select 146, 1, 'Y' from dual union all
  4     select 146, 6, 'Y' from dual union all
  5     select 146, 3, 'N' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 222, 4, 'Y' from dual
  8    )
  9  select exp_seek_id,
 10         sum(decode(abroad, 'Y', experience)) abroad,
 11         sum(decode(abroad, 'N', experience)) domestic
 12  from job_seek_experience
 13  where exp_Seek_id = 146
 14  group by exp_Seek_id;

EXP_SEEK_ID     ABROAD   DOMESTIC
----------- ---------- ----------
        146          7          3

SQL>
```

The *interesting* part for you are lines 9-14 (CTE isn't that interesting, is it?).

Answer (score 1):

use DECODE () its so easy

```
drop table omc.test;
create table omc.test (
EXP_SEEK_ID  NUMBER(5),
Experience  NUMBER ( 3) , 
Abroad  CHAR(1) 
); 

insert into omc.test values ( 146, 7, 'Y' ) ;
insert into omc.test values ( 146, 3, 'N' ) ;

commit;

select EXP_SEEK_ID,  SUM(decode( Abroad,'Y',Experience))  Abroad  , SUM( decode( Abroad,'N',Experience))  Domestic
FROM omc.test
group by EXP_SEEK_ID
```

EXP_SEEK_ID     ABROAD   DOMESTIC

---

```
    146          7          3
```

Comment: Hi, I would suggest store the values of Abroad  & Domestic in 2 different columns. if not it will be difficult for every SQL, check your business logic & usage of this table data. If you have already table like this & you cant re-design then you can create view on top it using DECODE () as i shown

Comment: That works.
But I am not able to implement this in my code given above.
Can you help me?

Comment: not able to understand ,  what not able to implement in code?